# NDVI data for the UK

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ndvi

I am trying to download NDVI data to input into ArcGIS, I have used USGS however I cannot download any Landsat data for my area. I'm looking for a time period between 2000-2018

The specific area I'm looking at is Yarnton mead floodplain, located near Oxey mead floodplain.

Can anyone suggest any places to download NDVI data to input into ArcGIS to create a NDVI map for this area as USGS has very little specific UK data?

Comment: JNCC Sentinel-2 indices Analysis Ready Data (ARD) Normalised Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI https://catalogue.ceda.ac.uk/uuid/51725f90c60a45e69f07a748a25b9729

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.